# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "xxx", referenced from: _main

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, clang

I have a c project in vscode。

test.c

```c
...
#include <mcl/pre.h>
...
int main(){
    pre_init();
}
```

mcl/pre.h

```c
void pre_init();
```

my launch.json looks like this

```js
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang++ build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "clang++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

task.json

```js
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-I", "/Users/johnzhu/Desktop/gitlabRepos/proxy-re-encryption/PRE_sample/include"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```js
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/System/Library/Frameworks",
                "/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

when I launch, error occurred：

Executing task: /usr/bin/clang -g /Users/johnzhu/Desktop/gitlabRepos/proxy-re-encryption/PRE_sample/src/pre_test.c -o /Users/johnzhu/Desktop/gitlabRepos/proxy-re-encryption/PRE_sample/src/pre_test -I /Users/johnzhu/Desktop/gitlabRepos/proxy-re-encryption/PRE_sample/include <

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_pre_init", referenced from:
_main in pre_test-22c5b9.o

any idea how to fix this

Comment: Where is the library that holds the compiled definition for `pre_init();`? With the header you are promising the compiler that it exists somewhere else. I don't see where you are linking with any `-lpre` (if that is what it is called) or adding the `pre.c` source so it can be compiled.? I'm not familiar with that library, so I can't give specifics.

Comment: You only have pre_init() signature but no method body is present for it, that's the problem